# How do I send a message to a list of usernames in Telethon library?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, telethon

1.I want to send a message to multiple users with this book, but it does not provide the desired output.

2.I make file py to name login and import login.in file:token,API_ID & API_HASH

```
from telethon import TelegramClient
from login import API_ID,API_HASH

class Telegram:
    def __init__(self ,message ,username1 ,username2=None ,username3=None) -> None:
        self.message = message
        self.username1 = username1
        self.username2 = username2
        self.username3 = username3




    def login(self):
        self.clinet=TelegramClient('userBot',API_ID,API_HASH)
        self.clinet.start()
        self.clinet.run_until_disconnected()


    def send_message(self):
        self.cli=TelegramClient('userBot',API_ID,API_HASH)
        self.cli.get_dialogs()
    
        users=[self.username1,self.username2,self.username3]
        for user in users:
        
            self.cli.send_message(user,self.message)
            print(f'sending message to {user}')


ig=Telegram('aled','Wo')
# ig.login()
ig.send_message()
```

3.Export terminal:

```
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation 
traceback
d:\A\py\telegram_bot\tel.py:27: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 
'MessageMethods.send_message' was never awaited
self.cli.send_message(user,self.message)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation 
tracebac
sending message to Wo
sending message to None
sending message to None
```

4.I have already logged into the Telegram account

Comment: Are you surprised by this result?  You only passed one username, so the second and third names were set to the default value in the function header, `None`.  Perhaps you should pass the list of users as a list, instead of limiting it to exactly three.

Comment: I have done this.
The main problem is not sending the message to the audience.

Comment: Most TelegramClient methods are asynchronous.  Have you tried `await self.cli.send_message...`?

Comment: Export terminal : `ValueError: Cannot find any entity corresponding to "Wo"`

Comment: That strongly suggests there is no user named "Wo".

Comment: In my previous robot, I executed it in a different way and it was correct
‍‍‍‍‍‍`users=[]`
`for user in users:`
        `if user.title == 'Wo':`
           `await user.send_message('Hi')`

Comment: In that case, `user` is an object, not a string.  The first parameter to `send_message` needs to be a Telegram object.

Comment: No, you need to go read about their API so you can create a user object from a username.